# React onChange function doesn't fire, not allowing me to change input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

This is my current Cadastro.js file:

When I try to edit the form input, it keeps the "pig" value declared inside my JS file, not allowing me to neither insert nor delete the value.

I've already rewritten the function, but it won't work in any shape or form, I must be missing something.

```
const CadastroColaborador = () => {
    
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        nome: "pig",
        matricula: "pig",
        senha: "",
        confSenha: "",
        funcao: "",
        tipo_acesso: ""
    })

    const {nome, matricula, senha, confSenha, funcao, tipo_acesso} = inputs

    const onChange = e => {
        setInputs({...inputs, [e.target.name]
        : e.target.value });
    };
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1 class="header">Cadastro de colaboradores</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text-container">
                <p>Utilize esta página para cadastrar novos colaboradores</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <form id='form-cadastro'>
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-1'>
                            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-input" id="nome" name='Nome' placeholder="Nome" value={nome} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-2'>  
                            <label for="matricula">Matricula:</label>
                            <input type='text' class="form-input" id="matricula" name="Matricula" placeholder="Matricula" value={matricula} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-3'>  
                            <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
                            <input type='password' class="form-input" id="senha" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha" value={senha} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-4'>  
                            <label for="senhaConf">Confirme a senha:</label>
                            <input type='password' class="form-input" id="senhaConf" name="SenhaConf" placeholder="Confirme a senha" value={confSenha} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-3'>  
                            <label for="func">Função:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-input" id="func" name="Funcao" placeholder="Função" value={funcao} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-field" id='form-field-4'>  
                            <label for="tipo-acesso">Tipo de acesso:</label>
                            <select class="form-selection" id="tipo-acesso" name='tipoUser' required>
                                <option>--SELECIONE--</option>
                                <option value="comum">Usuário comum</option>
                                <option value="super">Usuário administrador</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-btn">
                            <input type="submit" class='form-sub-btn' id='sub-btn' value='Cadastrar' />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: Try and do some console.log() debugging. Log your e  and e.target.name in the onchange handler, then log inputs at the end of the function (your state variable object). See how everything behaves. It'll give you a clue as to what might be wrong. For instance, the name attribute for your select element is tipoUser, but in your state variable you put tipo_acesso which is the id attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name contains a capital letter, so you can write `name="nome"` instead of `name="Nome"` or you can use `e.target.id` instead of `e.target.name`

By the way you can simply write `onChange={onChange}` instead of `onChange={e => onChange(e}`.

I think it would also be safer to call the `setInputs` function like this

```
const onChange = e => {
  setInputs(prevInputs => ({
    ...prevInputs, 
    [e.target.id]: e.target.value 
  }));
};
```

Comment: Yes, this would be the proper react way, in order to prevent unnecessary renders :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' class="form-input" id="matricula" name="Matricula" placeholder="Matricula" value={matricula} onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
```

Notice that "name" inside your input should match the input you are updating. name="matricula" should work.

onChange is adding to your object something like this:

`{matricula : "", Matricula: "" }`

Name should match, since you are updating like this:

```
setInputs({...inputs, [e.target.name]
```